# A set $E$ is countable iff there is a bijection $f: E \to E$ that does not bijectively map nonempty proper subsets of $E$ to themselves

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Show that a set $E$ is countable if and only if there is a bijection $f: E \to E$, such that the only subsets $F$ of $E$ such that $f$ (when restricted to $F$) is a bijection from $F$ to $F$, are $F = \emptyset$ and $F = E$. (Countable includes finite here.)

Intermediate set theory, Drake and Singh

The "if" part is what I am wondering about.

Comment: What is **your** actual **question**? I get that you’re wondering about the “if” part, but . . . so what?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in E$ be any point, and consider the set
$$F:=\{\dots,f^{-2}(x),f^{-1}(x),x,f(x),f^2(x),\dots\}$$

Comment: So f(F) will map each f^(-k)(x) to f^(-k + 1)(x), f^(-1)(x) to x, x to f(x) and so forth, so that it will be a bijection from F to F, and therefore has to equal E, which must be countable because k is countable. Thanks.